# How can I show that $\int_1^x \frac {O(\frac 1 t)} t \ dt$ converge?

Tags: calculus, analysis, number-theory, asymptotics

How can I show that $\int_1^x \frac {O(\frac 1 t)} t \ dt$ converge? I'm so confused of this material because of big-O notation.

Thanks

Comment: What is $O(1/t)$ by definition?

Comment: If it is $\mathcal{O}(1/t)$ as $t \to +\infty$ then does your integral converge as $x \to +\infty$ ? If it is $\mathcal{O}(1/t)$ as $t \to 0^+$ then does it  converge as $x \to 0^+$ ?

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac1t O\Bigl(\dfrac1t\Bigr)=O\biggl(\dfrac1{t^2}\biggr)\;$ and $\;\displaystyle\int_1^x\dfrac{\mathrm d\mkern 1mu t}{t^2}$ is convergent as $x$ tends to infinity.

Comment: Wait, I can't see the relation between $O(1/t^2)$ and $\int_1^x 1/t^2 dt$. Could you explain it for me?

Comment: @user366855 again what is [the definition of $f(t) = \mathcal{O}(1/t)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) ? And Bernard you have to insist on $x \to + \infty$ (different from $x \to 0^+$)

Comment: @user366855 We say that $f(x) = O(g(x))$ as $x \to \infty$ if and only if there exist positive constants $M, N$ such that $|f(x)| \leqslant Mg(x),$ whenever $x > N.$ That should help you understand what is going on.

Comment: @user1952009 Why $0^+$? The function is integrated on $(1,x)$, the integrand may even be undefined for $t<1$, so what's the point?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut the OP didn't mention we are looking at $\lim_{x \to +\infty}$ and that the $\mathcal{O}(1/t)$ is as $t \to +\infty$

Comment: @user1952009: For me, it went without saying. But probably you're right: it's better to avoid any ambiguity.

Comment: @Bernard I meant (as a teacher) you have to insist that the asymptotic comparison isn't restricted to $x \to +\infty$

Comment: I agree with you, and I updated my hint  to mention this is about $x\to\infty $.

Comment: @user1952009 Agreed, it has to be specified. However, given the context, it's almost obvious the comparison is at $+\infty$. Otherwise it would be at a finite value $a>1$, and it would be useless to know it's $O(1/t)$ there. But you are right, the information is missing.

Comment: Not any more (‘as $x$ tends to infinity’ is valid for the whole sentence).

Comment: @user1952009 By the way, there is a big mistake in my previous comment: I assumed $x>1$ because it's the upper bound, but you are right, $x$ could be less than $1$, of course.

Comment: @Bernard The problem is not your answer, but the OP's question ;-)

Answer (score 2):

**Assumptions:** Let's assume that the Big O notation you're using is "Big O as $t \to \infty$". Let's also assume that the class $O(1/t)$ consists of functions that are integrable on $(1,a)$ for all finite $a > 1$. This is, for instance, true for all continuous functions that are Big O of $1/t$ and (typically) any other functions you'd describe in this way in number theory. I'll also assume by the integral being "convergent" you mean that the function $\frac{1}{t}f(t)$ I discuss below (*i.e.*, the $\frac{1}{t}O(t)$ integrand) is integrable on $[1,x]$ for $x \geq 1$ and the value of the integral converges as $x \to \infty$.

**Solution:** Suppose $f(t) \in O(1/t)$. Then by definition there exist $C, T > 0$ such that

$$
    |f(t)| \leq \frac{C}{t}\qquad\text{for all }t \geq T.
$$

So here what (I think) you're trying to determine is (a) whether or not $\frac{1}{t}f(t)$ is integrable on $[1,x]$ for all $x \geq 1$ and, assuming this, (b) the improper integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{t}f(t)\,dt$ converges.

Regarding (a), note both $1/t$ and (by one of my assumptions) $f(t)$ are integrable on $[1,x]$ for all $x \geq 1$. Hence their product is integrable, as well. For (b), observe that

$$
    \int_1^x \frac{1}{t} f(t)\,dt = \int_1^T \frac{1}{t} f(t)\,dt + \int_T^x \frac{1}{t}f(t)\,dt,
$$

where the first integral on the RHS is (by (a)) some finite constant. To show that the second integral converges as $x \to \infty$, use the definition of $f(t) \in O(1/t)$ and the integral triangle inequality:

$$
    \left|\int_T^x \frac{1}{t}f(t)\,dt\right| \leq \int_T^x \frac{1}{t}|f(t)|\,dt \leq \int_T^x \frac{C}{t^2}\,dt = C\left(\frac{1}{T} - \frac{1}{x}\right).
$$

Now take a limit to obtain (b).